# How are static methods defined on constructor functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, static

Refer:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

So Object is a constructor function and here I see 2 types of methods defined -

1. Static methods - Object.create(), Object.assign() ...
2. Instance methods - Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty() ...

I understand how Instance methods are defined and used but no idea about static methods -

```
function Person() { }

Person.prototype.greetInstance = function () { return 'Hello!' };

let p1 = new Person();
console.log(p1.greetInstance()) // Hello!
console.log(Person.greetStatic()) // where should I define so this works ?? ‍♂️
```

Can someone please explain how to define greetStatic() ?

Comment: `Person.greetStatic = function() { };`?

Comment: Perhaps you should refer to [these docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) instead.

Comment: ok thank you. That was something silly I missed.

Answer (score 2):

Static properties or methods are just properties and methods that are defined on the object itself and not the prototype.

```js
function Person() { }

Person.greetStatic = function() { return 'Static hello!' }
Person.prototype.greetInstance = function () { return 'Hello!' };

let p1 = new Person();
console.log(p1.greetInstance()) 
console.log(Person.greetStatic())
```

Using the `class` syntax might help make this more clear, as you can use the `static` keyword in it. It's just *syntactic sugar* and he result will be exactly the same.

```js
class Person {
  static greetStatic() {
    return 'Static hello!';
  }
  
  greetInstance() {
    return 'Hello!';
  }
}

let p1 = new Person();
console.log(p1.greetInstance()) 
console.log(Person.greetStatic())
```

Comment: yes but class being syntactic sugar is what makes it harder to understand. How do I define method on "Person" (without using class). Using dot notation? is it same as static in class?

Comment: @mustafa1993 A `function` is little more than an object. So setting a static function is the same as assigning a function to a property. Using the dot notation is one way to do it and a very valid one.  The bracket notation `Person['greetStatic'] = function () {}` does exactly the same. [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) allows for more options to be set, but in the end has the same goal.